# problem on making canvas size dynamic using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I want to make the canvas size change dynamically when the size of the size if the window changes.
my canvas is in a frame and the frame is inside  the root.
as you can see in the code:

`canvas = tk.Canvas(elementFrame, height=920, width=920, bg="lightblue") canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=20)`

and this is the code of the frame :

```
elementFrame = tk.Frame(root)
elementFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
elementFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

I  tried to  create a function that takes the width and the height of the window when it's dimensions change

```
def resize_layout(event):
    window_width = event.width
    window_height = event.heigh
    canvas.config(height=window_height - 20, width=window_height - 20)
root.bind('<Configure>', resize_layout)
```

it didn't work at all and the canvas disappeared

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Since the canvas is in a frame, are you sure that the frame is resizing when you resize the window? Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

With the following changes:

- Change `elementFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` to `elementFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)`
- add `sticky="nsew"` to `canvas.grid(...)`
- add `elementFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)`

Then you don't need to bind `<Configure>` event to `root` at all.

Simple example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

elementFrame = tk.Frame(root)
elementFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
elementFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
elementFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(elementFrame, width=920, height=920, bg="lightblue")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

The canvas will be resized whenever root window is resized.